# How do I upgrade to Postgres 9.2?

Tags: postgresql

Just recently, I've read that **PostgreSQL 9.2** is released. My Ubuntu 12.04 has PostgreSQL 9.1.5 installed. How can I update to 9.2 version? I tried `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` but no updates for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 32):

Here's the instructions for adding the postgresql apt repository: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

**Quickstart**

Import the repository key from http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc:

```
wget -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list. The distributions are called codename-pgdg. In the example, replace squeeze with the actual distribution you are using:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ squeeze-pgdg main
```

Configure apt's package pinning to prefer the PGDG packages over the Debian ones in /etc/apt/preferences.d/pgdg.pref:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=apt.postgresql.org
Pin-Priority: 500
```

Note: this will replace all your Debian/Ubuntu packages with available packages from the PGDG repository. If you do not want this, skip this step.
Update the package lists, and install the pgdg-keyring package to automatically get repository key updates:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgdg-keyring
```

Once you've added that repository, you can do `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2`

Comment: I already have PostgreSQL installed, doing this will conflict my current installed?

Comment: it will install in it's own folder for postgresql-9.2.  If you find some of your commands (like pg_dump) point to postgresql-9.1 programs, you can change the symlink or just run the command from within the postgresql-9.2 directory. definitely back up databases before installing the new version just to be sure.

Comment: I take issue with that deprecation warning, since the PPA goes up to Quantal and the newer repo doesn't.  Both are late to Raring, which breaks the [recommended script](https://github.com/pgexperts/add-pgdg-apt-repo/blob/master/add-pgdg-apt-repo.sh).

Comment: Just for future reference, I was getting the error saying  /var/lib/postgresql/9.2/main is not accessible or does not exist

Solved it using 
    `sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql-9.2 postgresql-9.1`
    `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2`

Comment: Note, piping into sudo is **not** recommended. On my system, that causes the sudo prompt to be hidden, making the entire command appear to hang indefinitely.

Answer (score 6):

There is a new, official postgresql.org repository. It contains the newest versions of postgresql including 9.3 as of February 2014.
Please read the [detailed official instructions](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt). For Ubuntu 12.04 I used:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 pgadmin3
```

Comment: What provides the 9.3 version of pg_dump? Dpkg says it's still being provided by postgresql-client-common, which is stuck at 9.1.

Comment: @Cerin package `postgresql-client-9.3` contains `pg_dump`

Comment: Ah you're right. But it didn't update the symlinks in /usr/bin, which I'll just have to do manually.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql --cluster 9.2/main
```

Comment: I get this : `Error: Invalid version specified with --cluster`

Comment: On Askubuntu the individual asking a question will see every answer without needing to be individually addressed. Similarly you will be notified of every comment on your answer. Welcome to the site! Do you have any suggestion about Defensor's version error message?

Comment: This is just wrong. He's asking how to upgrade, not to connect to a 9.2 cluster.

Comment: AS far as I know, ppa:pitti installs the 9.2 in parallel to 9.1 - it just runs on another port. try 'psql -p 5433'.